# Xcode says that file doesn't exist

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm working with this project but everytime I try to build, xcode says that can't find Mainstoryboard because the file doesn't exist, but it exists.

I read a lot of things saying that the folder/file structure that I can see its not the same that xcode uses, but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Please add: XCode exact log output, a screenshot from Finder with the location of the missing file, and the right pane file proprties of the file from within XCode itself.

Answer (score 1):

Click on your project >> General tabs >> development info and make sure our storyboard's name is same as what you have in the main interface.
If the name is `main.Storyboard` then you should type "main" in the `Main Interface`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click your Project -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources, To check out The **Main.storyboard** is exist wheathor or not 
[image]

if not，add the **Main.storyboard** 
[image]